# Given an inequality of the form (x-a), (x-b), how do the factors (x-a), (x-b) split the number line into the following 3 parts?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I encountered this statement on the [U of T math department website](https://www.math.toronto.edu/preparing-for-calculus/2_inequalities/we_2_intervals.html) (under the first example):

> In general, if you want to solve an inequality of the form $(x-a)(x-b)
> > 0$ [...], notice that the factors split the number line into 3 parts: $x < a, a < x < b, x > b$.

I was wondering if anyone could explain why this is true, since I wasn't able to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Examine the sign of the function
$$
f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)
$$
on each of these three parts.  For simplicity, you can start with $a = 0, b = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Is it because of this?

We know both $(x - a)$ and $(x -b)$ must be either negative or positive, so the possibilities are:

either $x - a > 0$ and $x - b > 0$, or $x - a < 0$ and $x - b < 0$

which is the same as

either $x > a$ and $x > b$, or $x < a$ and $x < b$.

When we map these possibilities on a number line, we end up with the three parts described above.